# Looking for a jQuery plugin that can blur/hide text

Tags: jquery, plugins, blurry

I'm trying to find out if there is a jQuery plugin that can has the effect of literally blurring  elements on a page, so a user can't read them.  It's for a flashcard application I'm building, and I want to be able to hide the answer section of a card, making it appear unfocused as if you were looking at it through a blurry window, perhaps with some sort of overlay. jQuery has so many plugins and effects that I bet one like this exists, however googling for "jQuery blur effect" and the like predictably turned up results related to slide effects rather than what I'm looking for.  Has anyone heard of a plugin that can do something like this?

Comment: Not likely, jQuery can only operate within HTML/CSS, but Flash can.

Comment: Would there be a way to create some sort of image that when overlayed on an element would cause a blurring effect?  I can't think of what sort of image that would be offhand though...

Comment: Can you do some graphics stuff on the server side? SVG supports blurs, for drop shadows, for example, (in Inkscape, anyway) but most browsers haven't implemented that yet.

Comment: I'd probably so no to the server side graphics stuff because while it would be a great effect to have, I don't think I'd go into it that much to get it.

Comment: Re: overlay. You could theoretically use a png overlay with some transparency "holes" to show little bits of what's underneath. If you use photoshop you could use the difference clouds render on the alpha channel and adjust contrast until you get what you want.

Comment: Why not write a script that randomizes characters (most importantly the first and last letter) and then unrandomizes afterwards?

Comment: How important is it that the element is actually unreadable? Anything javascript can have a workaround for the user that simply disables javascript.  You'd be better off figuring out a way to render the text as an image if it's important the user can't figure out how to hack your blur job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had to implement something similar to this.  I just used a transparent PNG (well, obviously most of the PNG was NOT transparent) with little pockets of transparency.  Just enough so the user could get a hint of the text, but not really see it.  Not really a blur - more like what the board game Outburst does before you put the card behind the red decoder thing.  I just set the background image of an overlay div to the PNG and resize accordingly.

Comment: Seems to me that this is the only good way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with CSS3:

```
    #hidden {
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: #6374AB 0px 0px 20px;
}
```

Edit with more info: Currently only works in WebKit based browsers. Cross-browser text shadow info here:
[Creating Cross Browser Compatible CSS Text Shadows](http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/css/cross-browser-drop-shadows)

Comment: That's very much the type of effect I'm looking for, but I'm looking for it for a whole section of elements rather than just the text.  Might not exist though...

Comment: Some problems with this: (1) won't work on IE or Opera. (2) The user can still select the text and get an unblurry highlighted version.

Comment: Actually, it does work in Opera 9.

Comment: Oh, and selecting the text doesn't "unblurry" it. One would still have to copy and paste. :)

Comment: If it's going to be more than text, I don't think it exists client-side. You would likely have to look at ImageMagick or something similar…

Comment: I tested in Opera 10, and setting color to transparent hides the blur. Also, selecting does unblur it, at least on Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

how about using the sliding doors technique? you could have a small vertical sliced png that "simulates" a slice of blurred text with two rounded edge blur pieces to cap off each side. you could then create an overlay/toggled div with this blurring imageset that is similar width to the number of characters of the word and hide the word.

Answer (score 0):

There are some examples of doing this using css3 here: http://css-tricks.com/9053-fun-with-blurred-text/